# Radio button checked doesn't appear on UI

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I have 3 radio buttons, by default first one is selected, if I select other than first one radio button checked doesn't appear on UI, I'm using an onchange function on radio button there I'm setting the value using setValue method, value is updated but checked doesn't appear on radio button. Please help mt to fix this, I'm stuck with this since 3 days. Using angular reactive form approach.

on selecting any one of the radio button apart from first one, it should show as checked on radio button but it did not.

Comment: show us the [mcve] please